# What is the syntax error in my DoCMD.runSQL statement

Tags: syntax

I am having trouble with the syntax in the following code

DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Students_TBL SET StudentClass=" & Me.ClassTXT & "WHERE [Students_TBL].[StudentID]=" & Me.List2.Column(0, var)

If I replace Me.ClassTXT with ( for example) "'3P'" it will run and update  StudentClass field to 3P for the records  selected in List2 so I know the logic and process is correct.
But as soon as I try to use a text box on the form (Me.ClassTXT) to provide the StudentClass update value I get the following error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2EAe.jpg)

From the message I can see it is taking the data from the ClassTXT box correctly (and getting the first StudentID from the listbox but clearly a syntax error is causing a problem.
I have tried putting a space before the WHERE i.e " WHERE..." as the error message show 3PWHERE which makes me think they need to be separated some way but I have tried spaces. adding &" "& bewteen Me.ClassTXT and the "WHERE..." statement.
Can someone help! I am sure it is a simple syntax error but it has me beat.

Answer (score 0):

Still unable to find the syntax error so solved the problem in another way, as follows:
The data that is in List2 populates a table that is cleared and filled each time the data is moved to/from list2.
I now just run an update query (already created and not created in VBA) based on that table, linking it to the student table by a studentID field common to both tables. The update query only updates the students (in the students table) that are in the table created from list2 and sets the class for those students to the value in the ClassTXT box on the open form.

Basically what I was trying to do in VBA but just using an already created query.